# Fixing broken /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Google Compute Engine.

I was adding some commands to etc/network/interfaces, and restarted the vm to test them out. They were apparently incorrect, and I can no longer ssh into my vm. Is there a way I can edit the /etc/network/interfaces file without ssh to recover my vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on an article [Resolving getting locked out of a Compute Engine](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b). Minor corrections were made and the solution was checked for the Debian 9 image.

As in the case of bare metal, if you have physical access to it, you have a chance to gain access to the operating system. The same goes for GCE VMs: since you have access to the VM configuration, you can get inside.

**1.** Open the VM instance details:

```
GCP Console => Compute Engine => VM instances => instance_name
```

**2.** Stop the VM instance

**3.** Enable access to the Serial Console and add a startup script so that create a temporary user:

```
=> Edit =>  
  Enable connecting to serial ports = True 
  Custom metadata
    Key = startup-script
    Value = 
      useradd --groups "google-sudoers" user3
      echo "user3:password" | chpasswd
=> Save
```

**4.** Start the VM instance.

**5.** Once it started, connect to the console:

```
=> Connect to serial console
```

**6.** Press Enter. Login prompt appears. Enter username (`user3`) and password (`password`). You'll get to the bash shell. The logged-in user is a member of the "google-sudoers" group, so he can act as the root user:

```
$ groups 
  user3 google-sudoers 
$ id 
  uid=1004(user3) gid=1005(user3) groups=1005(user3),1000(google-sudoers) 
$ sudo su - 
root@instance-2:~#
```